# Monodevelop - Update the URL of a web reference

Tags: wcf, web-services, monodevelop

I have a monotouch application which accesses a WCF web service. This application is built within Monodevelop.

I have recently released a new version of this webservice. I.e. from http://localhost/v1/webservice.asmx to http://localhost/v2/webservice.asmx.

I need to update the url of web service in my Monotouch app and update the reference so that I can access the new methods. There does not seem to be a way to do this via monotouch. What is the simplest way to accomplish this task short of deleting and re-adding the reference?

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem possible via the GUI indeed.

It seems that the URL is stored in `Reference.svcmap`.

You could try editing this file, then running `Update Web References`. I have not tried though.